# Using ActiveRecord classes with legacy tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many legacy databases from which I need to pull raw data. Each of the tables in the database have arbitrary names, and an arbitrary collection of fields. I have been getting access to these fields with the following class:

```
class Frt < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :legacy
  set_primary_key "point"
end
```

When I reach the point in my code where I know the table name, I can call:

```
Frt.set_table_name "table"
t = Frt.find_by_sql("blah")
something = t.field_name + t.other_field_name
etc...
```

The problem is that I've realized that this locks the accessible field names to whatever table I select first. If I try to change the table with another call to the `set_table_name' method, it changes the attribute for the class, but any new instances will still have the same set of fields as the first one. So far, in my app, I've not needing anything else, but I'm expanding the program in a way in which I know it will bite me in the butt down the road.

I've tried `Frt.send :set_table_name "new_table"', hoping that it would cause ActiveRecord to do it's magic again. It doesn't.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to keep the convenience of ActiveRecord, but get it to dynamically remap its fields for whatever table I need loaded?

Comment: can you post the rest of your code? where do you make the ActiveRecord obj?

Comment: Isn't this what I have above? 't = Frt.find_by_sql("blah")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own post, but I guess I didn't explain it very well. In case someone else comes along after this, what I needed to do was issue a call to the "Frt.reset_column_information" method. I was revisiting this issue, and just dumped all the methods on the ActiveRecord class, and found that one lurking in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but [Magic Model Generator](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/) claims to create models for tables automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this would be to create a model for each legacy table you need to interact with - no dynamic table name remapping required, and it works right out of the box.

Comment: I've taken your advice, but the fields will still change per type of table, depending on various factors.